# Why do I get duplicate results using scope on Heroku, but not on my local machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this scope in Subscriber.rb:

```
scope :notify_today, 
joins(:skills => :positions).
where('positions.created_at > subscribers.created_at AND positions.created_at > ?', 1.day.ago)
```

On my local machine it works fine, but on Heroku it returns each object twice.

I managed to fix it with a group:

```
scope :notify_today, 
joins(:skills => :positions).
where('positions.created_at > subscribers.created_at AND positions.created_at > ?', 1.day.ago).
group('subscribers.email, subscribers.id, subscribers.last_email_at, subscribers.created_at, subscribers.updated_at')
```

I just wondered if this is the right way to fix it and why Heroku duplicates the results?

**EDIT:**

Database associations:

```
Subscriber
has_and_belongs_to_many :skills

Skill
has_and_belongs_to_many :subscribers
has_many :positions

Position
belongs_to :skill
```

I'm using the default database that comes with Rails.

**Subscriber.notify_today.to_sql** gives the same thing on my local machine and on heroku:

```
   "SELECT \"subscribers\".* 
    FROM \"subscribers\" 
    INNER JOIN \"skills_subscribers\" ON \"skills_subscribers\".\"subscriber_id\" = \"subscribers\".\"id\" 
    INNER JOIN \"skills\" ON \"skills\".\"id\" = \"skills_subscribers\".\"skill_id\" 
    INNER JOIN \"positions\" ON \"positions\".\"skill_id\" = \"skills\".\"id\" 
    WHERE (positions.created_at > subscribers.created_at AND positions.created_at > '2011-02-07 10:15:27.098261')"
```

Comment: Use the `to_sql` method on the result of the scope and see the difference between the two SQL statements. You're joining 3 tables it looks like. Where is the `subscribers` table coming from in your conditions?

Comment: I ran to_sql on my local machine's console and on heroku's and it gave the same results. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Tis weird that you're getting different results locally. Just at a guess, Heroku uses a postgresql database by default even if you specify something else in your database.yml I believe.

It might be that your local database understands your SQL differently to postgresql or is joining tables differently..

What database are you using on your local machine?

Comment: Heroku ignores database.yml and uses Postgres unless you enable the RDS plugin.

Comment: I use the default database that comes with Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see the associations between Subscriber, Skill, and Position.

Did you really mean to do join with nested associations, or did you mean to do a join of Subscriber with multiple assocations, `joins(:skills, :positions)`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to do join with nested associations. See the update in question above.